# How to encrypt cookies in Xamarin?

Tags: mobile, cookies, owasp-top-ten

I have a Xamarin application which creates a few files in `/data/data/my.app.com/app_webview` after using it.

[image: Files created after running the application]

The problem is that the cookies file is a file which contains session cookies. According to the [OWASP top 10 Mobile](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Mobile_Top_10_2016-M2-Insecure_Data_Storage), this is not secure.
[image: Cookies stores]

How do I securely store my cookies in Xamarin?

Comment: I'm not sure this qualifies as Insecure Data Storage.  Is there anything that is stored in the cookies other than the session token?